# Java code for 2-4 balanced search tree node?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

Can someone show me the basic structure of a [2,3,4 balanced search tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqrqYXkth6Q&list=PLBB2FC97598A3B254&index=26) node in Java?  I am not sure how to represent a 3 key node. Should I use an array of size three? Or should I have a left entry (entry=key +value object), middle entry and right entry fields?

And how does the left child and right child work out? In a binary search tree the left and right childs are for a node. In a 2,3,4 tree, the left and right child seem to be for each key. So should a 2,3,4 tree node itself be an object that holds 3 binary tree nodes, instead of holding 3 entries?

Answer (score 1):

The "traditional OO" option of having separate classes for the 4 node variants (0 for leaf, 2, 3 or 4 children otherwise) is awkward, because references to the node would then have to be updated, leading to having to store a back reference to the parent and updating the parent every time the number of children changed.

Instead, it seems far more simple and performant to break the "state affecting behaviour rather than subclass" anti-pattern and use LinkedLists for both the values and the child nodes:

```
public class Node<T> {
    LinkedList<Node<T>> children = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<T> values = new LinkedList<>();

    public Node(T value) {
         values.add(value); // there is always a value
    }
    // other methods to find, insert, delete, etc
}
```

Using a LinkedList gives you constant time (ie `O(1)` time complexity) on all operations (although n=4 is small, still every bit helps), the ability to iterate without an iterator via `next()`, which is needed to iterator conveniently over both lists simultaneously, and a more convenient API for balancing operations.

Comment: I know I might be asking too much. But would it be possible to give the code for insert operation on this? Also how do you enforce that there are exactly 2,3 or 4 children? And exactly 1,2 or 3 keys per node.

Comment: @foo yes, it is "too much" (too broad a question). Regarding the limits, do it in code. At worst there are only 4 possible cases you need to code for